# How to make a 14x5 grid of Radio Buttons in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I want to make a grid of 14x5 radio buttons in my Web page but I am facing the following problems :
[image: Distorted]
**1)**

[image: Long Straight]

**2)**

Either I am not able to align it in perfect grid or it is going straight down, It would be very helpful , If someone can help me out with the approach to align it in 14x5 Grid (if possible) like this:
[image: OMR]

I am not sharing my html/css code of the webpage as that involves django template tags doing different things which would overcomplicate things ,and I have to write a longer question to explain the backend logic unneccesarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grid-template-columns` to repeat it in a column in the below code I have set `repat(5, 1fr);` it will return this in five-column automatically

```
<style>
.main_class {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, under the main class you have to contain all the radio buttons.